# Can I use Google Cloud Platform to host my website?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, web-hosting

I have a simple static website and I was wondering if I can host my website in google cloud?

I am not sure how much this can cost and how I can figure this out.

I already hosting my website somewhere but I am not happy with their email services. And I was thinking if I can host with Google Cloud and I can use google email as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Google App Engine can host your static website. Here's how I have my site setup.

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func init() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("web"))
    http.Handle("/", fs)
}
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

[image: Project Layout]

You'll need the Google Cloud SDK and app-engine-go component to test locally and deploy your website.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/download

Once that's installed you can open a terminal and navigate to the folder with app.yaml in it then run `gcloud app deploy`

After the deploy is finished a new version will show up in your app engine account. You can test the deployed version by clicking on the version name in the table. 
https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions

Then you'll need to follow the instruction to point your domain to google's hosting
https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains

If you use more than the free quota then they'll charge you.

For example, 1GB of bandwidth per day is free then the $.12/GB after that
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Requests

You can set your daily spending limit to $0 to prevent charges, but this will cause your website to go down once your free quote is reached.
https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings

You can keep an eye on the cost from the app engine dashboard
https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine

Comment: golang beats java when it comes to startup time.

Answer (score 3):

If your requirement is to host static website (with not much traffic), I would suggest Google App Engine Standard than Google Cloud engine. With google app engine standard, if your site doesn't have any hits, it would be automatically taken down. Once there is a hit, it would be brought back automatically. You would save lot of money. Check the prices at https://cloud.google.com/pricing/

Regarding email, if you want google to host your business emails, its not free, you might want to start at https://gsuite.google.com/products/gmail/

Comment: About how many seconds does it take a simple static file server to boot up after it goes back online? Booting up in seconds is fast, but I wouldn't want a user waiting more than 2-3 seconds.

Comment: Its all depends on your application. If its mostly static content, it shouldn't take long. But if there is continous traffic, it would never be taken down.

Comment: I’m using Heroku with a Node.js static file server and it takes about 7 seconds to boot up. I’m going to compare the boot time to GAE’s standard environment with a Go static file server

Comment: Ok. You need to think about boot timing only if there won't be any hits for long time. If you are so particular about boot time, you can configure minimum number of active instances.

Comment: That's true, Google gives 28 free instance hours a day so it'd be free to run one website 24/7, but if I want to host more than one it'll cost me.

Comment: I just created a static file server with Go on GAE and moved my website files in(3MB). The instance boots up in less than a second compared to Heroku's 7 seconds. Not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can but it's depend upon your requirement, like open source plateform can be host in share hosting whereas nodejs etc must be host ion dedicated server example vps.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**:
The most *cost effective* way of hosting a static (HTML) website on Google Cloud Platform is to store it in a cloud storage bucket. Since Cloud Storage comes with an always free tier, this can save a lot of money over time. See this article for details on hosting it on Cloud Storage https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website

Google's [Firebase hosting](https://firebase.google.com/) would be another viable option.

**Email**:
IAAS/SAAS Email is not automatically built into hosting on GCP, but if you transfer your domain to [Google Domains](https://domains.google/) then you can seamlessly sign up for Googles G-Suite [Gmail based] email for your domain.